# What color profile to use for scanning?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, scanner, color-profiles

I have a Dell v305 printer/scanner/etc...  What color profile should I use with scanning photos?  I am scanning them into Photoshop CS4.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, what you want is to reporduce the exact color of what you scanned. Selecting a color profile alone doesn't guarantee that, though it might bring you closer.

I'm not sure which one suits your devices, but you might want to read this up on [scanner calibration](http://desktoppub.about.com/cs/colorcalibration/a/cal_scanner.htm). It has some information on ICC color profiles too.

Good Luck!

Comment: note the article suggests calibrating your monitor as a preliminary step.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting scanning, I'd strongly advise calibrating your monitor (if you haven't already) so that you can usefully judge the output from your scanner on the screen.

Windows 7 has a decent calibration utility built in (type 'calibrate display' into the Windows search box) or see Jeff Atwood's article [Computer Display Calibration 101](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000965.html) for a good background and useful links.

One this has been done you will be in a much better position to judge a scanner profile by directly comparing the original with the scanned image on screen.

Comment: I am scanning on the laptop.  Not sure that screen calibration applies.

Comment: A lot of (non-expensive) laptops can be problematic when it comes to colour fidelity as the colour you see depends so much on the viewing angle (try looking at something like the yellow background to the 'Sponsored Links' section of a Google results page at different viewing angles). Definitely still need to calibrate though.